# Select Items from List<object> by conitaining List<guid> in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-objects

I am having the ListAllUsers . User having propeorty id(as Guid),name(as String),address(as String). I am having another List ids of users id which are selected from ui. I want to get List selectedUsers, where ids from AllUsers. I am trying to fetch it by LINQ. can i do this by single statement , without multiple itterations? how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do something like:

```
var selectedUsers = allUsers.Where(user => selectedUserIds.Contains(user.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is:

```
var selectedUsers = selectedUserIds.Select(id => allUsers.First(user => user.id == id))
```

This will throw an exception if one of the selectedUserIds doesn't map to a user which might be what you want. The method by Frédéric will silently swallow.

Comment: could not get exactly, can you explain ? what is "map" here ?

Comment: What I mean is that if you are given an id and there is no user with that id it will throw an exception.